# How to get correct bookmark (webloc) icon to show?

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

Safari Bookmark icons of (.webloc) are only showing generic document icon. How to get correct '@' icon to show?

It's the webloc document created when pulling (drag & drop) URL from Safari address to desktop.

Comment: I've seen this article recommended: https://macreports.com/mac-displaying-wrong-generic-document-icons-for-files-folders-fix/ , but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the correct icon.
2. Convert it to `.icns` with [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/png-to-icns).  (Note: If you convert an image to `.icns`, the image must be 16 × 16, 32 × 32, 48 × 48, 128 × 128, 256 × 256 or 512 × 512)
3. Right click on the `.webloc` file and click get info
4. Drag the `.icns` file you just made into the icon on the top left corner of get info.

If that doesn't work, let me know.  I'd be happy to help you! :)

Comment: I mean, sure, you can give each individual file an icon with the Finder, but that doesn’t answer the question of how to fix this problem with .webloc icons in Catalina, especially if you have dozens or hundreds of .webloc files.

Comment: I guess I misread the question.  I thought they just wanted to know how to add an icon in general.